# I want to set height of container according to contained images in it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set height of the container after analyzing height of images. There is a container with two images in it:

- if the orientation of both images is horizontal then its container should get particular height(110px)
- if one image is horizontal and one is vertical then some other height(130px) to container
- if both images are vertical then another height(160px)

I have written code, where I will first analyze orientation of each image then another function which will give height to container accordingly. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/2nnK2/1/) of what I have tried so far.

I want to know, how can I set height to container?

Answer (score 2):

First, note that you have multiple elements with the same ID; `frame`. Change that to a class, otherwise this isn't valid HTML.

To set the `height` of the container with the class `frame`, do something like this:

```
if($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {
    //do other stuff
    $(this).parents(".frame").height(110); //this sets to 110px, can be anything
}
else {
    $(this).parents(".frame").height(130); //this sets to 130px, again, can be anything
}
```

I hope that helped you in any manner!

Comment: that doesnt solved the problem. and i can not give different ID's, there will be many such containers, i cant give diff id's

Comment: @user1531746 Use `classes` instead of IDs.